# Spring mvc does not show errors anymore after redirect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have been creating a form with Spring. I used to have one page which was working all ok, all validation was working and redirect was taking me back to the page with the model, errors, and all the fields were filled in.

Now, however,since I have created another page that is more JS based that redirects to my initial application form. *(it uses sessionstorage if that makes any difference)*

the "debug" sysout from my complete form controller completes all steps and redirects me back. it must be something to do with code in #fig1 but I can't figure out and I am not too sure where to start looking for an answer even.

**my controller #fig1**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newApplication", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String retryApplication(Model theModel) {
    if (!theModel.containsAttribute("applicant")) {
        theModel.addAttribute("applicant", new Applicant());
    } else {
        Applicant theApplicant = new Applicant();
        theModel.addAttribute("applicant", theApplicant);
    }
    return "application-form";
}
```

**my complete form controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSendEmail(HttpServletRequest request,@Valid @ModelAttribute("applicant") Applicant Applicant,
        BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)throws Exception {

    //checks form for errors
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("found errors");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.applicant", result);
        System.out.println("adding flashattribute to binding result");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("applicant", Applicant);
        System.out.println("adding flashattribute to applicant");
        return "redirect:/newApplication";

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was absolutely right. the issue was in fig#1 after realising that I was creating an empty object if there were any errors all I had to delete is code below.

The mystery though how it was working before, haha.

```
} else {
    Applicant theApplicant = new Applicant();
    theModel.addAttribute("applicant", theApplicant);
}
```